# Systemd - Set MAC address and IP address

Tags: systemd, linux-kernel, ip, mac-address, systemctl

I am trying to use systemd to set the MAC address and IP address of eth1 on my board.

**MAC address**
To set the MAC address, have created the following service:

*/lib/systemd/system/eth1mac.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Setting up MAC address
Before=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /etc/eth1mac

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service points to the shell script here:
*/etc/eth1mac*

```
#!/bin/sh

ifconfig eth1 down
ifconfig eth1 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
ifconfig eth1 up
```

This is working fine.

**IP address**
To set the IP address, have created the following service:
*/lib/systemd/system/eth1ip.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Setting up eth1 IP address
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /etc/eth1ip

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service points to the shell script here:
*/etc/eth1ip*

```
#!/bin/sh

ifconfig eth1 192.168.160.218
```

**Issue**
This service is working, but isn't invoked every time we reboot the board. Do I need certain dependencies to ensure this service is re-run at reboot?

Answer (score 4):

Network is configured via [`.network`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html) and [`.link`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html) files when using systemd's [systemd-networkd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd.service.html). The default location for these files is `/etc/systemd/network`.

Example: Rename interface which uses MAC address `74:d1:2c:2c:6e:d8` name to `phy0` and change MAC address to `11:22:33:44:55:66` in `/etc/systemd/network/10-phy0.link`:

```ini
[Match]
# Match card's MAC address
PermanentMACAddress=74:d1:2c:2c:6e:d8
    
[Link]
Description=Ethernet Port 1
# Rename interface to phy0
Name=phy0
# Override MAC address (spoof MAC address)
MACAddress=11:22:33:44:55:66
```

Set IP address in `/etc/systemd/network/phy0.network`:

```ini
[Match]
# Match interface name
Name=phy0    
    
[Network]
Description=Interface phy0 (network)
DHCP=no
# Static IPv4 or IPv6 address with CIDR
Address=192.168.1.123/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
# DNS server address
DNS=192.168.1.1
Domains=mynetwork.lan
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use systemd for this? I wouldn't recommend making your own systemd services with custom shell scripts as it is hard to maintain and can get messy quickly.

The more common way to set a static IP address and MAC address on an interface is to set it in the `/etc/network/interfaces` config file (assuming a Debian based Linux system).

For example, appending this to the config:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    address 192.168.160.218
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    hwaddress ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

There is also a way to configure network interfaces using [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd) daemon that is part of systemd. You would have to edit the corresponding `.network` file for the interface that you want to configure. systemd-networkd should then configure this interface for you during bootup.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jack. I don't have /etc/network/interfaces file. I am developing on Angstrom OS.

Comment: could you give me an example of what the .network file would look like for eth1 please?

Comment: From what I recall in my brief time using Angstrom Linux, it uses Connman to manage network interfaces, DNS, etc.
Perhaps give this a try?: https://rocketboards.org/foswiki/Documentation/SettingAStaticIPAddressInAngstrom